# Restrict Index View to User's Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, authorization

I'm working on a Ruby project and running into a roadblock.  It's a simple thing, but I keep running into errors so I'm turning to SO for help.

I need to restrict a view to records created by a particular user.  In this case, a supplier's orders. Here's my current index controller (using will_paginate gem to limit to 30 per page):

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_supplier!

  def index
    @orders = Order.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
  end
```

Right now, ALL orders show rather than the desired - only orders put in by the particular supplier should show in the index.  I attempted to use something along these lines, but no luck:

```
def index
 @orders = Order.current_supplier.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
end
```

Using devise for suppliers.

Comment: try `current_supplier.orders.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)` i assume `supplier` also have `has_many :orders`

Comment: Ah - that seems to have revealed another problem, there was no supplier_id column on orders

Comment: and yes, supplier `has_many :orders` and order `belongs_to :supplier`

Comment: so if supplier authorized, you have a helper `current_supplier`.

Comment: once I added the supplier_id field and fixed the association problems this fixed my issue.  Must have left this off my todo list and created a lot of headaches. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Devise is used for authentication, what you need is something for authorization, I recommend having a look on a gem specific for this purpose, such as [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan), you define the rules in the ability file, and then it will add the conditions on the controller queries so that you don't need to define the same rules every time you fetch those records.

If you don't want to add this kind of complexity to your code then you could simply use the supplier object to get the orders instead of the order class it self. for example:

```
# all orders without conditions
Order.all

# orders restricted only to this supplier
current_supplier.orders
```